# What are the possible consequences for using a credit card from “free credit card” videos on YouTube for free trials?

Tags: united-states

Currently there is an [Epic Games-Discord](https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/p/discord--discord-nitro) promotion going on, where the applicant can receive a three-month lasting free trial of Discord Nitro subscription.

Now obviously, as many companies do nowadays, they require a credit card to redeem the offer. I searched for a credit card on YouTube, and I found one video where a Nigerian man showed his PayPal Business Debit Mastercard and specifically said “You can do whatever you want with it, send the money to different countries, different places”.

If that is the rightful owner, he did consent to the public of it being used for any purposes. The debit card still had the “Activate Your Card with the PayPal app” sticker, so potentially it could be not activated. I am aware that PayPal may have terms of them prohibiting any kinds of sharing their services’ credentials.

The video was later taken down by YouTube for “violating community guidelines” by sharing billing information on the site. I have downloaded the video and the video itself is a proof that the information was not used against his will (again if that is the rightful owner).

Also, it is a free trial, which will not renew since I cancelled the renewal and removed the billing information afterwards (a day later when I found out that is possible).

Did I violate any laws, and can I face any charges or in the worst case, go to prison?

I should also clarify that I am a minor as now (16 years old).

Comment: How can you say it wasn’t against his will? You can’t see the guy with the gun just off frame.

Answer (score 2):

### Discord can ban you from their platform

While you are not in [breach](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-12-05/legality-of-using-someone-elses-bank-card-to-buy-them-a-coffee/10580604) of any law or contract with the credit card company Discord are likely to be unhappy that your activity caused them to be in breach with the card company.

Discord has absolute discretion under their [terms](https://discord.com/terms) to ban you for any or no reason. If they became aware of your actions they might just do so.